# Including images in MBunit report exports

Tags: webdriver, mbunit

We execute MBunit tests in a CI system that generate HTML reports, as well as machine readable reports. I'd like to attach images to the HTML reports.

When running via Gallio.Icarus, the images show in the execution log. Unfortunately, they are not available to the HTML report. MBunit saves the images in "C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Temp\Gallio\".

Background and Goal: We run WebDriver tests in all our supported browsers through our CI system. When tests fail, we spend a lot of time debugging. A picture speaks a thousand words, so I'll attach a screen shot to the report. Running Icarus to see the output would be a manual process, which defeats the point of automated testing.

Code sample: (The RemoteScreenShot implementation is a port of [this java RemoteScreenShot](http://code.google.com/p/selenium-remotewebdriver-screenshot/source/browse/src/main/java/RemoteScreenshot.java)  to C#)

```
    [SetUp]
    public void SetUp()
    {
        var capabilties = new DesiredCapabilities(new Dictionary<string, object>() {{"browserName", "internet explorer"}});
        // This is a subclass of RemoteWebDriver that supports screenshots.
        _driver = new RemoteScreenShot(new Uri(HubServer), capabilties);
        _google = new GoogleHome(_driver);
    }

    [Test]
    public void TestScreenShot()
    {
        _driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("http://www.google.co.uk");
        var screenShot = ((ITakesScreenshot)_driver).GetScreenshot();
        screenShot.Should().Not.Be.Null();
        using (var stream = new MemoryStream(screenShot.AsByteArray))
        {
            var image = new Bitmap((stream));
            TestLog.Write("Hello");
            TestLog.AttachImage("Screenshot", image);
        }
    }
```

Comment: What runner are you using on the build server?

Comment: We are using Gallio.Echo

Comment: Can you raise this on the gallio-user mailing list, please? I have some further questions :)

Comment: Posted to MBunit.User. I also posted to gallio-user, but I haven't been a member of that group long enough -- sent to moderators.